# Двух уровневый список

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, datagrid, usercontrol

Мне нужно в Windows Forms на форме отобразить двух уровневый список. А именно данные записной книжки, в которой есть контакты и группы в которые эти контакты объедены( как бы папки). Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой контрол лучше использовать для отображения таких данных и как именно его можно использовать?

Comment: Делать сколько-нибудь нестандартные контролы с WinForms — мучение. Я всегда советую даже не начинать с этим фреймворком каменного века. Возможно, вам поможет [owner draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: WPF для ваших целей самое-то!

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, то скорее всего подойдет `ListView`. У него есть коллекция `Groups` - это будут ваши группы контактов. А в них уже добавляйте контакты. Если степень воженности еще больше, то тогда посмотрите в сторону `TreeView`